# MVC4 Modelbinding with class properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have a setup with `Client`s that have `User`s.

Simply, the `Client` just has a

```
[Required]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

and the `User` has - amongst its properties - a

```
[Required] 
public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
```

When it comes to creating `User`s, the `User`s are created under the specific `Client`s (obviously)

So: in my `User` create page, I throw the `Client` Id into the Viewbag so that I can send it through with the `User` to my creating controller.

The first issue I hit is that `Modelstate.IsValid` is `false` - this is because the `Client` the `User` model creates doesn't have a `Name` as is required. Quick fix: also throw in the Name and return that as well.

This passes validation and I can retrieve the `Client` properly in the code and assign it to my `User` and save the new `User` yada yada...

I'm sure this isn't a strange, one-off style setup. There has to be a 'proper' way to do this rather than the fudging I am currently doing.

1) How can I 'properly' provide/keep the `Client` that I want to assign the new `User` to?

2) If the above isn't possible, what's the best way to do it? I currently store the `Client.Id` in the `User.Client.Id` field, and short of using `[Bind(Exclude="Client")]`, which completely removes the `Client` from the `User` binding, I'm not sure how to pass the `Client` data around and validate it all.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would not be an issue if you were using View Models rather than passing your entities directly to the view.

One of the reasons to use View Models is that your views have different requirements than you data model.  In this case, you don't need the Client information in the view at all (unless you are displaying that somewhere).  You are just creating a new user, and when you post your view model, you will create a new entity from the information submitted.  At that point, you can simply assign the ClientID and save the new User.

Comment: Ah, I see. I had expected a different style of functionality, I didn't realise I needed an intermediate step. Thank you.